# How to show the PhysicsBody outline in ARKit?

Tags: swift, scenekit, arkit

I have a class as below in arkit

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, ARSCNViewDelegate, 
                                        SCNPhysicsContactDelegate  {
    override func viewDidLoad() { }
}
```

The truly reason is in the link
[How to set SCNPhysicsBody or SCNPhysicsShape?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70131497/how-to-set-scnphysicsbody-or-scnphysicsshape)

How to set it so I can see the PhysicsBody outline? Then I can debug to check if the SCNPhysicsShape is reasonable or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This option helps visualizing the `physics shapes` for nodes with attached SCNPhysicsBody objects:

```
sceneView.debugOptions = [.showPhysicsShapes]
```